# How do I get mean functions to work when I use piping?

Tags: r, dplyr

This is probably a simple question, but I'm having trouble getting the mean function to work using dplyr.

Using the mtcars dataset as an example, if I type:

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>%
select (mpg) %>%
mean()
```

I get the "Warning message:
In mean.default(.) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" error message.

For some reason though if I repeat the same code but just ask for a "summary", or "range" or several other statistical calculations, they work fine:

```
data(mtcars)

mtcars %>%
select (mpg) %>%
summary()
```

Similarly, if I run the mean function in base R notation, that works fine too:

```
mean(mtcars$mpg)
```

Can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`, you can use `summarise()` whenever you're not changing your original dataframe (reordering it, filtering it, adding to it, etc), but instead are creating a *new* dataframe that has summary statistics for the first dataframe.

[image]

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

gives the output:

```
  mean_mpg
1 20.09062
```

PS. If you're learning `dplyr`, learning these five verbs will take you a long way: `select()`, `filter()`, `group_by()`, `summarise()`, `arrange()`.

Comment: The original question is looking for a single number as the final output, like `mean(mtcars$mpg)`. It is wise to use `summarise(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))`, but the output is a data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pull` to pull out the vector.

```
mtcars %>%
  pull(mpg) %>%
  mean()
# [1] 20.09062
```

Or use `pluck` from the `purrr` package.

```
mtcars %>%
  purrr::pluck("mpg") %>%
  mean()
# [1] 20.09062
```

Or summarize first and then pull out the mean.

```
mtcars %>%
  summarize(mean = mean(mpg)) %>%
  pull(mean)
# [1] 20.09062
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the answers above explain how to get the mean using piping or tidyverse.  None of them explain why the mean() function does not work with dplyr::select().

I believe the answer is that the result of dplyr::select() is the same as the original object, in this case a data.frame.  A data frame is not a vector, even if the data frame only has one variable in it.  So the following code works, while demonstrating *why* the previous code does not:

```
mtcars %>%
select (mpg) %>%
unlist() %>%
mean()
```